# Why am I getting a undefined variable error?

Tags: php

I have a class member in PHP that looks like this:

```
function hidden($defaultSort=""){
    $defaultSort = 'a';?>
    <input type="hidden" name="sort" id="<?php print $this->id;?>sort" value='<?php print $defaultSort; ?>' />
    <?php print $defaultSort;
}
```

When I call this function I get the following source in firefox

```
<input type="hidden" value="&lt;br /&gt;&lt;b&gt;Notice&lt;/b&gt;:  Undefined variable: defaultSort in &lt;b&gt;/www/sptdev/htdocs/includes/v7/sptSearchBox.php&lt;/b&gt; on line &lt;b&gt;24&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;" id="searchFormSearchsort" name="sort"/>a
```

Any ideas why I am getting the Undefined variable error?

**More details:**
The line 24 that the error is coming from is the line with the hidden input.

I have discovered that this works as expected in IE8.

```
<input type="hidden" name="sort" id="searchFormSearchsort" value='a' />a
```

This doesn't make much sense to me since PHP is server side and this should have nothing to do with the browser.

**UPDATE** -
The problem seems to be that I was highlighting and selecting "View Selection Source" in Firefox. When I just use "View Page Source" it looks fine.

Comment: The output differs from what I can see in the code. Please always make sure the code is the same as the one that generated the output. (the attribute order differs, who knows what else does.)

Comment: Worksforme: http://codepad.org/PUb9iQSR

Comment: Use echo instead of print. Print returns a Boolean on whether it was successful or not, where echo return void

Comment: -1 Did you even attempt to use the search feature before posting? This is one of the main questions asked on stackoverflow. just look at the side bar...

Comment: In every question I found it seemed obvious to me that the variable never got defined. In mine it seems obvious to me that $defaultSort is defined.

Comment: It's always obvious the variable is defined until you find out you're looking at the wrong code. :)

Comment: Are you sure the HTML output is current? Try clearing the browser cache.

Comment: As the markup is rendered by your server (which does not know whether you are regularly browsing the website or inspecting the markup in any way), this can not be related.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function hidden($defaultSort=""){
    $defaultSort = 'a';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="sort" id="' , $this->id , 'sort" value="' , $defaultSort ,'"/>';
  print $defaultSort;
}
```

**Edit:**
I just tried this code and it works fine. Try to copy-paste it as it is and see if it works for you.

Comment: Was a great idea but I got the same result.

Comment: PHP uses `.` not `,` for concatenation

Comment: echo allows multiple parameters separated by commas. The comma is fine here.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct. Probabily you're watching in wrong place (maybe you're modifying a parent class and an overrided method)